CIFS Share not responding while writing a file
We have mounted a NetApp share in SUSE Linux 15 SPS 04. We can read/list the files in the share without any issues but the moment we try writing a file, it hangs/does not respond. Even we can't list the files.

/var/log/messages gives error as below:
kernel: [506753.705726][ T7101] CIFS: VFS: \\XX.XX.XX.XX sends on sock 000000001ca9c250 stuck for 15 seconds
kernel: [506753.705740][ T7101] CIFS: VFS: \\XX.XX.XX.XX Error -11 sending data on socket to server
//xx.xx.xx.xx/drive  /mnt/test cifs nohandlecache,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials2.txt,uid=user,forceuid,gid=group,forcegid,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino 0 0


mtab entry:
//xx.xx.xx.xx/drive /mnt/test cifs rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict, username=user, domain=domain,uid=100002617,forceuid,gid=1002,forcegid,addr=xx.xx.xx.xx,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,nohandlecache,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=1 0 0



